# Seed codable models with fake data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm about to start working on a Swift 4.1 project, where we're using `Codable` to populate and serialize our models. We created a custom protocol, implementing `Encodable` & `Decodable` with custom `JsonEncoder` and a custom `JsonDecoder`, configured to read out our API's data format correctly.

With this project, there's one problem: The API is not yet available when we start. What we'd potentially like to do is fake data into all the models (as in, create 10-20 entities of the models) within Swift. This so we can test logic e.d. written for the app.

Is there perhaps a way to automate this process? Maybe through a way comparing to `Laravel`'s seeders? Or is there perhaps a working package that serves this purpose? Thanks :)

Comment: Why not put a JSON file in your app's bundle and load the JSON from the file instead of your API. Then none of your other code has to change at all.

Comment: @rmaddy This would however involve manually writing all of the json files, which is something we'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: If you want fake data, the data needs to be written in some form or another. Faking a JSON file is the simplest from the point of minimal code changes and it lets you test your code properly.

Comment: I second rmaddy's approach. One caveat however: it doesn't make any sense if you don't know *exactly* how the json is going to look once the API is ready. You'd have to rewrite your parsers if it is different in the end. What I've done for a project was to create placeholder objects and add those to the data where you would add the actual parsed data. Not ideal, but that way you won't have to know what the API responses will look like.